How to install a bundle to sling using Docker
Hi I wanted to try creating a sling application with the help of a docker image.
I started the docker image using:

docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 apache/sling:snapshot

Then I created a maven project SlingSample with following pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SlingSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>
  <name>Sling Sample Bundle</name>
  <description>A sample Sling servlet bundle.</description>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.8</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Activator>org.example.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Export-Package>org.example.*</Export-Package>
            <Sling-Servlet-Paths>/bin/helloworld</Sling-Servlet-Paths>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

My HelloWorldServlet looks like:
package com.example;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletPaths;
import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletResourceTypes;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component(service = {Servlet.class})
@SlingServletPaths("/bin/helloworld")
@SlingServletResourceTypes(
        resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default",
        selectors = "HelloWorldServlet",
        extensions = "txt")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write("Hello, World!");
    }
}

Then I created the jar using

mvn clean install

I created a folder opt/sling/install in the docker image and then pasted the jar there using:

docker cp target/SlingSample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar <container_id>:/opt/sling/install/

I tried hitting :  http://localhost:8080/bin/helloworld which gives the error:

Resource at '/bin/helloworld' not found: No resource found (404)
The requested URL /bin/helloworld resulted in an error in org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.defaults.DefaultErrorHandlerServlet.

I also checked if my bundle SlingSample is there in http://localhost:8080/system/console/bundles. But No.
Am I doing something wrong, or should I do something more than this? Ca somebody please help?

I tried the above steps and hoped to see Hello word in server but failed.

The simplest way to install bundles is to use the sling-maven-plugin. As you can see in the pom.xml snippet from the Sling project archetype, this is achieved by using the following (slightly adjusted)
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <slingUrl>http://localhost:8080/system/console</slingUrl>
                    <user>admin</user>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Once this is added to your pom you can run mvn package sling:install and the bundle will be deployed.

On top of that, I think you can completely remove the configuration section of the maven-bundle-plugin, the default values are good enough and you don't need to tweak them for your use case.
